# How to upload and style svg logo?

Tags: images, themes, css, block-editor, svg

WP beginner here. I'm trying to upload an `svg` logo to my site. The logo can be accessed [here](https://easyupload.io/ogtc1a). If you open it in the browser and inspect it, it should show the `svg` tags around the object.

I've installed the `SVG Support` plugin and uploaded the image and set it as the logo of my theme. The logo is displayed in `img` tags but not as an `svg`. How would I change its color?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it’s in an img tag, you can’t.

Comment: Welcome to wpse! If you want it either black or white you can use css `filter: brightness(0) invert(1);` (that will make it white for example). If you want it in any other color, as jacob said, you can't

Comment: one option, you could use css and make the svg a background mask and change the color of it that way.
.my-logo{
    background: #000000;
    mask: url('path/to/svg') center no-repeat;
}
 this will require custom CSS in the customizer, but should be doable without editing any theme template files

Answer (score 1):

You could paste the SVG in the Custom HTML block and style it with CSS.

There is also https://wordpress.org/plugins/icon-block/ which supports pasting a custom icon and facilitates styling it.